# removing some empty table details and adding classes and width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to remove the empty code from table with jquery and add some class to the table tags

like i am trying to remove `<td class="faux_align"></td>` and `<th class="faux_align"></th>` from the table and check if the table already has a class of `table` - do nothing and if it does not have a class of `table' - do add the class`table` to the table tag.

and also checking if the width attribute is defined within table and if not, add width as 100% and if defined but width is not 100%, make its width 100%

I am trying something like this:

`$('table > tr > td').remove();`

and same with `th` tag, but i am confused how do i do with remaining this in one single jquery function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$('table').addClass('table').attr('width', '100%').find('td.faux_align, th.faux_align').remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table width="">
  <tr>
    <th class="faux_align">faux</th>
    <th>text</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="faux_align">faux</td>
    <td>text</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <th class="faux_align">faux</th>
    <th>text</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="faux_align">faux</td>
    <td>text</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```